# Outlook : How to get email from Recipient field?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto

I'm attempting to get the email address typed into the *To* field of a compose mail window.

I try to get the Address property of a Recipient, which according to VS, should give me the email.

I am instead receiving a string that looks like this:

```
"/c=US/a=att/p=Microsoft/o=Finance/ou=Purchasing/s=Furthur/g=Joe"
```

How can I get the email address in the recipient field?

My code so far:

```
List <string> emails = new List<string>();

if (thisMailItem.Recipients.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Recipient rec in thisMailItem.Recipients)
    {
        emails.Add(rec.Address);
    }
}
return emails;
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this ?

```
emails.Add(rec.AddressEntry.Address);
```

[Reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527867%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)

EDIT:

I don't have the right environment to test so I'm just guessing all this, but how about

```
string email1Address = rec.AddressEntry.GetContact().Email1Address;
```

or `.Email2Adress` or `.Email3Address`

Also there is,

```
rec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Address
```

that you might want to try.

Comment: I just tried that, and rec.Address and rec.AddressEntry.Address return the same thing. meow.

Comment: GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress was the answer :)

when there are multiple 'address' types registered to the user, the Address property defaults to things other than email, so you have to specify which type of address. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
private string GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(Recipient recip)
        {
            const string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";

            PropertyAccessor pa = recip.PropertyAccessor;
            string smtpAddress = pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS).ToString();
            return smtpAddress;

        }
```

This is available on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868695.aspx)

I have used the same way to get email addresses in my application and its working.

Answer (score 2):

the `AddressEntry` also has an `SMTPAddress` property that exposes the primary smtp adress of the user.

Comment: For future reference, in VS2010 it's     rec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySMTPAddress

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps or how accurate

```
it is, a sample

    private string GetSmtp(Outlook.MailItem item)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item == null || item.Recipients == null || item.Recipients[1] == null) return "";
                var outlook = new Outlook.Application();
                var session = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                session.Logon("", "", false, false);
                var entryId = item.Recipients[1].EntryID;
                string address = session.GetAddressEntryFromID(entryId).GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
                {
                    var rec = item.Recipients[1];
                    var contact = rec.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                    if (contact != null)
                        address = contact.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
                {
                    var rec = item.Recipients[1];
                    var contact = rec.AddressEntry.GetContact();
                    if (contact != null)
                        address = contact.Email1Address;
                }
                return address;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```