# MeetingItem Recipient. How to get email

Tags: vba, outlook

I found a similar question but for c# [Outlook : How to get email from Recipient field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036995/outlook-how-to-get-email-from-recipient-field)
In this question there is also no correct answer.
Still, I tried some of the answers from this thread
`recipient.AddressEntry.Address` <= returns same thing as 
`recipient.Address` what I used till yet and what gievs me following result:

```
"/o=POST/ou=Zuerich/cn=Recipients/cn=eicherr"
```

How can I get email adress of recipient?

I tried also `.AddressEntry.GetContact().Email1Address` and `.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Address` this all not works for me.

Here is a MSDN docs explanes how to get email adress but I don't undestand how can I use it in my code [Obtain the E-mail Address of a Recipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient)

my code:

```
Dim Msg As Outlook.MeetingItem
Set Msg = Item
Set recips = Msg.Recipients
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient

For Each recip In recips
    Dim email as String
    email = CStr(recip.Address)
    Debug.Print email
End For
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Recipient.AddressEntry.Type <> "EX"`, just use `Recipient.Adddress`. Otherwise use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`

Comment: `Recipient.Address` returns `"/o=POST/ou=Zuerich/cn=Recipients/cn=eicherr"` but `.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress` works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the link I inserted finally helped me solve this problem.

```
For Each recip In recips

    'Obtain the E-mail Address of a Recipient
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
    Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor

    Dim email as String
    email = CStr(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS))
    Debug.Print email

End For
```

Comment: PR_SMTP_ADDRESS is not guaranteed to be present. Do use ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress